# How to return an access a split string while using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text file which is being read using File.ReadLines(filepath). It's filled with first and last names delimited using a :. Is there a way using LINQ in which I would be able to access the first and last name in the foreach loop for the returned datatype?

```
// john:doe
// david:smith
// michael:rogers

var Names = File.ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select(line => line.Split(':'));

foreach (var list in Names) 
listbox1.Items.Add(list); //(first name) before : 
listbox2.Items.Add(list); //(last name) after :
```

Comment: Is it mullti column `ListBox` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're almost there.  All you're missing is to get the firstName from the first item in the array and the last name in the second item.

```
foreach (var list in Names) 
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(list[0]); //(first name) before : 
    listbox2.Items.Add(list[1]); //(last name) after :
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list[0]` is the first and `list[1]` the second

```
listbox1.DataSource = Names.Select(a => a[0]).ToArray();
listbox2.DataSource = Names.Select(a => a[1]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I assume it is *not* multicolumn `ListBox`.

Use `SelectMany` to flatten the hierarchy after splits.

```
listbox1.DataSource = File.ReadLines(filepath)
                          .SelectMany(line=>line.Split(':'));
```

Or, use `AddRange` method and do this

```
 ListBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadLines(filepath)
                             .SelectMany(line=>line.Split(':')
                             .Cast<object>()  // I think this is redundant remove if not required.
                             .ToArray()
                        );
```